# Find how many words in a file contain a number in them?

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, wc

I am trying to find the total number of words in a specific file that contain a number.  Not a specific number, I'm just looking for words that contain any number at all.  I tried using the grep and wc commands with the following:

```
grep [0-9] filename | wc -w
```

I'm getting an output of "no match".  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what's the _exact_ output you get?

Comment: grep: No match.

Comment: Followed by a 0 on the next line

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Are you sure the error message is from `grep`, rather than from your shell? You should always quote grep patterns like `[0-9]` to prevent your shell from attempting to glob them - what happens otherwise depends on whether there is a matching filename in the current directory, which shell you are using, and what its settings are. For example, with no match, in bash with the `failglob` option, you would get an error like `bash: no match: [0-9]`. I just tried it in `csh`, and I do indeed get `grep: No match.` - are you using `csh`?

Comment: The grep will return a full line if it fires. The `wc` will count all words in the line, regardless if they contain numbers, so `echo 1 22 3333 abc | grep [0-9] | wc -w` returns `4`, which I doubt is what you want. You should look at `awk`.

Comment: @steeldriver I'm using bash.  I tried quoting the grep pattern and got a real output.  I think that was the answer, thank you!

Comment: It's unclear whether the string `100` should be counted, as it's not a word that contains a number but rather just a number.  Also, a string such as `utboe10` is obviously not a "word" with the number 10 at the end, at least not in English.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're not getting any matches because your shell is interpreting the brackets using its own syntactic rules. They need to be in quotes. But even if it weren't for that problem, yours would count all words (or any kind) that occur on the same line as a numeral. That's not what you want.

I suggest this:

```
grep -wo '[[:alnum:]]*[0-9][[:alnum:]]*' filename.txt | wc -w
```

This looks for strings containing 0 or more alphabetical characters followed by at least one number then 0 or more alphabetical characters.

The `-w` option will only count whole words. The `-o` option puts each match on its own line and only prints the matches, so you won't get other words on the same line. `wc -w` counts the words.